# What kind of algorithms can be run on this kind of dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

We are running a survey majorly on our ordering system like delivery, curbside and in-store pickup. We are collecting the ratings for ordering experience, how likely the customer would recommend our products to others, and some comments of their experience. Can you guys help me to find out the possibility of an ML algorithm to run on this type of data?

Comment: Have you tried any ML algorithm? In example logistic regression or decision tree?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have comments from your customers, you could do some sentiment analysis. If you have customer demographics, you could do clustering and segmentation to better understand them better to the benefit of your business.